# How to display data inside a button - Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, rendering

I am using Ruby on Rails, where I am trying to render data onto the browser.

The following is the data I want to display when the button is clicked:

```
<td><%= index += 1 %></td>
     <td><%= pod.metadata.name %></td>
     <td><%= pod.metadata.creationTimestamp %></td>
```

I created my onclick button with the following code:

```
<button class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" style="margin:10px;" onclick="myFunction()">
            <%= index += 1 %>
</button>
```

How do I format my code, so that when the button is clicked, the data is displayed on a different page?

Comment: Can you show controller ? i think your data is a array. If it is real array, `<% data.each do |f| %> <button><%= f.name %></button><%end%>`

Answer (score 0):

The rails 'way' will have you calling a controller from your 'calling view' and that controller call the 'result view' rendering the content you intend to see.

**In the calling view**

```rb
<%= form_with url: "/search", method: :get do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :query, "Search for:" %>
  <%= form.text_field :query %>
  <%= form.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

**This will generate the following HTML**

```html
<form action="/search" method="get" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
  <label for="query">Search for:</label>
  <input id="query" name="query" type="text" />
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Search" data-disable-with="Search" />
</form>
```

Therefore, it will call the action `/search` (wich you need to have mapped in your routes for some controller) passing the parameter `query` that you can read from `params[:query]`.

From that controller you can render the page you with the result view.